# Is there any way that I can navigate to Viewcontroller which is middle of the UInavigationcontroller stack

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have Collection View Controller `PatientList` -> on selection of cell navigates to `PatientdetailView` -> on click of button navigates to `startDignosisView`. This is Navigation controller stack. Now from Patient List I have button **"ADD"** that navigates to `AddpatientView`, from where I have to navigate to `StartdignosisView` without disturbing Navigation stack. How can I do it?

Comment: Arpana are you using storyboard?

Comment: Ask more clearly, your question can't 100 % understandable!

Comment: Can you please share your problem in detail? your question can't 100 % understandable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (UIViewController *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
{
    if ([controller isKindOfClass:[NeededViewController class]])
    {
        [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller
                                          animated:YES];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: My Navigation stack is -PatientListView->detailView->StartDiagosisview..
Patient List view has button called Add that navigates to AddPatientView. now from AddpatientView there is button that supposed to navigate me to StartDiagnosisView.
in AddPatient I am using above code as
for (PatientListCardView *controller in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
    { if ([controller isKindOfClass:[self class]])
        { [self.navigationController popToViewController:controller
                                                  animated:YES];
            break;}}
Am I doing anything wrong

Comment: @ArpanaSakpal I can only help in providing you a solution... can not code on your behalf.. sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

```
if let viewControllers = self.navigationController?.viewControllers {
    var newStack: [UIViewController] = []
    for viewController in viewControllers {
        newStack.append(viewController)
        if viewController is StartdignosisView {
            break
        }
    }
    self.navigationController?.viewControllers = newStack
}
```

Comment: objective C please

Comment: you should tag `objective C` in your question if you want in it!! I have edited your question btw!

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
   some *vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"some identifier you add to a vc in the storyboard"];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Just set the identifier to the storyboard for that view controller.

Answer (score 0):

**If you are not using storyboard** then follow the below steps:

See if you Add Patient and then directly navigate to StartDignosisVC then you will not be able to pop to PatientDetailVC

You can do any one from these two:

**First:**

Try to present your AddPatientVC, add new and then dismiss it and follow your old stack path.

**Second:**
One ADD button action instantiate your AddpatientView like this:

```
AddPatientVC *obj = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"AddPatientVC"];
```

And similarly navigate to StartdignosisView with setting a flag that you are coming from AddPatientVC:

```
 StartDignosisVC *obj = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"StartDignosisVC"];
    obj.isFromAddPatientView = true
```

When you press Back button from StartDignosisVC then check if you came from AddPatientVC to directly pop it to Patient list.

**If you are using storyboard** then you can do the following see attached screen shot:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer Dheeraj but I am not using Storyboard

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Mayank for your answer: following code worked in my case.
 [self.navigationController popToViewController:[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] animated:YES];